# How to validate a vine url

Tags: php, regex

I would like to know how to validate a vine.co URL using php

Here is a demo URL

https://vine.co/v/hnVVW2uQ1Z9

All vine.co URL's have https://vine.co/v/

So I' guessing that URL can be validated using regex by using https://vine.co/v/. If someone can point me out how to do this will be much appropriated.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of regex. Use [`stripos` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php):

```
// assuming $url is input URL to your code
$vineURL = 'https://vine.co/v/';
$pos = stripos($url, $vineURL);

if ($pos === 0) {
    echo "The url '$url' is a vine URL";
}
else {
    echo "The url '$url' is not a vine URL";
}
```

Comment: Couldn't hurt to add case-insensitivity as well, as https://Vine.co/v/ is also "valid".  Probably wouldn't come up much, but could happen.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed: Thanks, good point. Added `strtolower` function call.

Comment: No prob.  And actually… I might actually check the result of $pos===0.  Because "Xhttp://vine.co.v/" would pass as a valid url as well.

Comment: The `strtolower()` is a bit superfluous since PHP already has a case-insensitive version of `strpos()`.

Comment: @anubhava yes it works thank you very much. Sorry for the delay to replay my internet was down

Comment: Ok changed to use `stripos` isntead. @zack: Glad it worked out.

Comment: The reason for using the identical operators (that also check for the type of the value) "===" or "!==" is that strpos() might return "0" for match at the beginning or "false" for no match which cannot be distinguished by "==" or "!=". See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20298808/1438393) above.

Comment: @AmalMurali: Reason for using `$pos===0` is explained in Dan's comment above.

Comment: @zack: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Comment: @anubhava: A valid point. However, I think a regex might be a better solution. Anyway, for something simple, this should work, too :)

Comment: @AmalMurali: It is quite funny that I am finding on other side of regex today after answering hundreds of question on regex on SO :)

Comment: @anubhava: 100? It's actually more than 2000 and you even have the regex gold badge. :)

Comment: @AmalMurali: Oh yes I didn't notice there are more than 2k reps on 1800+ answers on regex :)

Comment: @anubhava yes i did it. Thanks you all again for you contributions.

Answer (score 1):

The regex for this would be very simple:

```
$pattern="@^https://vine.co/v/\w*$@i";

$input_url="https://vine.co/v/hnVVW2uQ1Z9";

if(preg_match($pattern, $input_url)){
    echo "Valid URL";
} else {
    echo "Invalid URL";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex:

```
$url = 'https://vine.co/v/hnVVW2uQ1Z';

if (preg_match("#^https?://vine.co/v/[a-z0-9]{10}$#i", $url)) {
    // valid
} else {
    // invalid
}
```

If you're sure that the the string to validate will always be a URL, then you can simply check if it contains the vine URL format. This can be accomplished by using the less memory-intensive, [`stripos()`](http://php.net/stripos) function:

```
if (stripos(trim($url), 'https://vine.co/v/') !== FALSE) {
    // valid
} else {
    // invalid
}
```